# The kashrut of honey in Lion's belly in the parable of Samson

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, tanach, agada-stories-legends

In the book of Judges, 14:18,   וַיֹּאמְרוּ לוֹ אַנְשֵׁי הָעִיר בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי, בְּטֶרֶם יָבֹא הַחַרְסָה, מַה-מָּתוֹק מִדְּבַשׁ, וּמֶה עַז מֵאֲרִי; וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם--לוּלֵא חֲרַשְׁתֶּם בְּעֶגְלָתִי, לֹא מְצָאתֶם חִידָתִי. ( And the men of the city said unto him on the seventh day before the sun went down: What is sweeter than honey? and what is stronger than a lion? And he said unto them: If ye had not plowed with my heifer, ye had not found out my riddle). Samson's riddle is presented to the Philistines at his wedding: What is sweeter than honey, and what is a wilder than lion? without going into the essence of the riddle and its solution. According to the commentators, the riddle is based on a real case that was caught in a convention, that the bees nested in lion's belly that Samson killed. Samson gave the honey to his righteous parents to eat. And the halachic question is whether it is permissible
to eat honey made in dead lion? Moreover, didn't his parents investigate where this honey came from?

Comment: Shulchan aruch yore deah mentions that any added taste to honey is lifegam

Comment: The Pri Megadim, in a kind of random Sefer called מתן שכרן של מצוות, has a discussion of this in חקירה א׳. See here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34107&st=&pgnum=4